# Web Form do not update data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, webforms

My web applicatin has two web forms using Master Page that access data tables in SqlServer database:

1 - Autoridade.aspx that shows data and search them

2- Autoridade_Atualizar.aspx that updates data in table lideranca

Autoridade.aspx has a GridView that show data and uses asp:HyperLinkField to redirect to Autoridade_Atualizar.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gwDados" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="Não Existem Autoridades Cadastradas...">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="Nome" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="partido" HeaderText="Partido" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="aliado" HeaderText="Aliado" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cargo" HeaderText="Cargo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="lotacao" HeaderText="Lotação" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="atuacao" HeaderText="Atuação" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Autoridade_Atualizar.aspx?id={0}" Text="Editar" DataNavigateUrlFields="id" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

When I exchange the values of the DropDownLists fields and click on Update Button of the Form do not alter the data on gridview.

```
asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlUpdate" Visible="true">
    <h1>Atualizar Autoridade</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="CodAutoridade" runat="server" Text="Cód. Autoridade"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbCodAutoridade" Text="2013" Enabled="false" CssClass="radiusInput disable" runat="server" Width="546px"></asp:TextBox>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label Text="Nome" ID="label1" runat="server" Width="88px"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbNome" Text="" CssClass="radiusInput" runat="server" Width="654px" Height="16px"></asp:TextBox>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="Cargo" runat="server" Text="Cargo"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcargo" DataTextField="carg_cargo" DataValueField="carg_cd_cargo" CssClass="radiusInput" runat="server" Width="454px"></asp:DropDownList>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="Partido" runat="server" Text="Partido"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlpartido" DataTextField="part_sigla" DataValueField="part_cd_partido" CssClass="radiusInput" runat="server" Width="254px"></asp:DropDownList>
        </li>
        <li>
```

Below  is my C# code:

```
protected void bntAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnUpdate();
    }

    private void OnUpdate()
    {

        mdc = new ModelDataContext();
        try
        {
            lid_lideranca lideranca = mdc.lid_liderancas.First(aut => aut.lid_cd_lideranca == int.Parse(tbCodAutoridade.Text.Trim()));


            tbNome.Text = lideranca.lid_nome;
            ddlcargo.SelectedIndex = ddlcargo.Items.IndexOf(ddlcargo.Items.FindByText(lideranca.lid_cd_partido.ToString()));
            ddlpartido.SelectedIndex = ddlpartido.Items.IndexOf(ddlpartido.Items.FindByText(lideranca.lid_cd_partido.ToString()));
            tbDescricao.Text = lideranca.lid_cargo2;
            tbemail.Text = lideranca.lid_email;
            tbfacebook.Text = lideranca.lid_facebook;
            tbtwitter.Text = lideranca.lid_twitter;
            tbendercomercial.Text = lideranca.lid_endereco_comercial;
            tbenderesidencial.Text = lideranca.lid_endereco_residencial;
            tbfonecelular.Text = lideranca.lid_fone_celular;
            tbfoneresidencial.Text = lideranca.lid_fone_residencial;
            tbfonecomercial.Text = lideranca.lid_fone_comercial;
            ddlmunicipio.SelectedIndex = ddlmunicipio.Items.IndexOf(ddlmunicipio.Items.FindByText(lideranca.lid_cd_cidade_atuacao.ToString()));
            ddlbasealiada.SelectedIndex = ddlbasealiada.Items.IndexOf(ddlbasealiada.Items.FindByText(lideranca.lid_cd_base_aliada.ToString()));
            ddlorgao.SelectedIndex = ddlorgao.Items.IndexOf(ddlorgao.Items.FindByText(lideranca.lid_cd_orgao.ToString()));

            mdc.SubmitChanges();
            Response.Redirect("Autoridade.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            mdc.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are not changing the values of the **lideranca** record in the underlying database, but rather using the values to set the text and selected index values of your controls.  You are calling SubmitChanges of your data context but are not modifying the record.  If your gridview is bound to the lid_liderancas table, those records will always be the same since they are not being modified.

Comment: So. How do I make this? Can you show me with a example code?